# Pointer to pointer to nested structure

Tags: c, nested, structure, binary-search-tree

There are two structures for BST

```
typedef struct _price {
    double price;
    char* shopname;
} pricing;

typedef struct _bstnode {
    int id;
    pricing** pl;
    int nr_of_prices;
    struct _bstnode *left;
    struct _bstnode *right;
    struct _bstnode *parent;
} bstnode;
```

I need to make a function that can add and update price and shop name in BST Node. One Node may contain many shops and prices

```
void updatePrice(bstnode* root, int id, char* shop, double price){
//to do
}
```

I can add a single shop name and price but how to add several objects?

```
(*(root->pl))=malloc(sizeof (pricing));  // ---??
(*(root->pl))->price=price;
(*(root->pl))->shopname=shop;
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want a dynamic "array" of pointers to `pricing`? Then first think how you would create a dynamic array in general using e.g. `malloc` and `realloc`. Then think about if you really need an array of pointers to the structures, or just an array of structures.

Comment: a Node from binary search tree have a array of structures 'pricing' i need to add and edit structures in the node, but i can't get access to them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If nr_of_prices belongs to pl, this will add dynamically one object:

```
int oldidx = root->nr_of_prices++;
root->pl = realloc( root->pl, root->nr_of_prices * sizeof(*root->pl));
root->pl[oldidx] = malloc(sizeof(pricing));
root->pl[oldidx]->price = price;
root->pl[oldidx]->shopname = shop;
```